# count most repeated value per group in hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hdp

I am using hive 0.14.0 in a hortonworks data platform, on a big file similar to this input data:

| tpep_pickup_datetime | pulocationid |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-28 23:32:52.0 | 100 |
| 2022-02-28 23:02:40.0 | 202 |
| 2022-02-28 17:22:45.0 | 102 |
| 2022-02-28 23:19:37.0 | 102 |
| 2022-03-29 17:32:02.0 | 102 |
| 2022-01-28 23:32:40.0 | 101 |
| 2022-02-28 17:28:09.0 | 201 |
| 2022-03-28 23:59:54.0 | 100 |
| 2022-02-28 21:02:40.0 | 100 |

I want to find out what was the most common hour in each locationid, this being the result:

| locationid | hour |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 23 |
| 101 | 17 |
| 102 | 17 |
| 201 | 17 |
| 202 | 23 |

i was thinking in using a partition command like this:

```
select * from (
   select hour(tpep_pickup_datetime), pulocationid
      
        (max (hour(tpep_pickup_datetime))) over (partition by pulocationid) as max_hour,
        row_number() over (partition by pulocationid) as row_no
        from yellowtaxi22
   ) res 
   where res.row_no = 1;
```

but it shows me this error:
*SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies. Underlying error: Invalid function pulocationid*

is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You were half way there!

The idea was in the right direction however the syntax is a little bit off:

1. First find the count per each hour

   ```
   Select pulocationid, hour (tpep_pickup_datetime), count (*) cnt from yellowtaxi22 
        Group by pulocationid, hour (tpep_pickup_datetime)
   ```
2. Then add the `row_number` but you need to order it by the total count in a descending way:

   select  pulocationid ,  hour ,  cnt  , row_number () over ( partition be pulocationid order by  cnt desc ) as row_no from
3. Last but not the list, take only the rows with the highest count ( this can be done by the `max` function rather than the `row_number` one by the way)

Or in total :

```
      select pulocationid ,  hour from (

        select  pulocationid ,  hour ,  cnt  , row_number ()
 over ( partition by pulocationid order by  cnt desc ) 
as row_no  from (
        Select pulocationid, hour (tpep_pickup_datetime), count (*) cnt from yellowtaxi22 
        Group by pulocationid, hour (tpep_pickup_datetime) ))
        Where row_no=1
```

Comment: Thank you su much! I am happy to know that I was taking the correct approach, despite just being half way there xD. However, I still have an error: **FAILED: ParseException line 7:60 cannot recognize input near ')' 'Where' 'row_no' in subquery source** should I alias each subquery?

Comment: @Freshguy12 Add Alias to the sub Query before where row_no=1

Answer (score 0):

```
with raw_groups -- subquery syntax
(
 select 
  struct( 
   count(time_stamp), -- must be first for max to use it to sort on
   location.pulocationid , 
   hour(time_stamp) as hour 
  ) as mylocation -- create a struct to make max do the work for us
 from 
  location 
 group by 
  location.pulocationid,  
  hour(time_stamp)
),
grouped_data as  -- another subquery syntax based on `with`
( 
 select 
  max(mylocation) as location -- will pick max based on count(time_stamp)
 from 
  raw_groups 
 group by 
  mylocation.pulocationid
) 
select --format data into your requested format
 location.pulocationid, 
 location.hour 
from 
 grouped_data
```

I do not remember hive 0.14 can use with clause, but you could easily re-write the query to not use it.(by substituting the select in pace of the table names) I just don't find it as readable:

```
select --format data into your requested format
 location.pulocationid, 
 location.hour 
from 
 ( 
 select 
  max(mylocation) as location -- will pick max based on count(time_stamp)
 from 
  (
 select 
  struct( 
   count(time_stamp), -- must be first for max to use it to sort on
   location.pulocationid , 
   hour(time_stamp) as hour 
  ) as mylocation -- create a struct to make max do the work for us
 from 
  location 
 group by 
  location.pulocationid,  
  hour(time_stamp)
)
 group by 
  mylocation.pulocationid
)
```

Comment: If you found my comment helpful please upvote.  If you are comfortable marking it as the answer I'd appreciate you marking it so when you have time.